# Using vue-i18n to translate the default value for a Vue component prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-i18n

I'm using `vue-i18n` to handle localization in my app. I need to apply localization to the default value for a component prop:

```js
export default {
  name: 'ExampleComponent',
  props: [{
    prompt: {
      required: false,
      type: String,
      default: $t('example.prompt.default')
   }]
}
```

`$t` is obviously not in scope as shown, but it seems that at the point the default value for the prop is being evaluated, `this` is not the component itself either, so `this.$t` is also undefined.

What's the best way to use VueI18n to translate the `default` value for a prop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access `$t` in a callback function as the callback is evaluated in the context of the created component.

```
prompt: {
  required: false,
  type: String,
  default: function () {
    this.$t('example.prompt.default')
  }
}
```

The downside here is that the value will be `undefined` in the `beforeCreate` life-cycle hook. If you need it there, then your best bet is to instead set the default value to the key of your i18n definition (example.prompt.default), and use `this.$t(this.prompt)` instead.

Comment: This doesn't work. I think you are missing a `return` statement in the default function. Also it is not responsive to a locale change.

Comment: It does work, or try es6 syntax: default: () => this.$t('error.couldNotGetData')

Comment: I am getting 
```Property '$t' does not exist on type '{ type: StringConstructor; required: boolean; default: () => String; }'```

Comment: I don't think this can work because `this` isn't available in the `default` function, as per [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html?redirect=true#:~:text=Note%20that%20props%20are%20validated%20before%20a%20component%20instance%20is%20created%2C%20so%20instance%20properties%20(e.g.%20data%2C%20computed%2C%20etc)%20will%20not%20be%20available%20inside%20default%20or%20validator%20functions.).

Answer (score 0):

You can import the `VueI18n` instance from where you imported it.

```js
import i18n from '../i18n'

export default {
  name: 'ExampleComponent',
  props: [{
    prompt: {
      required: false,
      type: String,
      default: i18n.t('example.prompt.default')
   }]
}
```

i18ns.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

function loadLocaleMessages () {
  const locales = require.context('./locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i)
  const messages = {}
  locales.keys().forEach(key => {
    const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i)
    if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
      const locale = matched[1]
      messages[locale] = locales(key)
    }
  })
  return messages
}

export default new VueI18n({
  locale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE || 'en',
  fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'en',
  messages: loadLocaleMessages()
})
```

Comment: Problem i have with this solution is that it is not reactive when changing locale